# Entity Framework core won't update database

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I successfully created an Entity Framework Core migration and updated the database with it.

Then after I added another class, I created a second migration called "update1" which created a class of the same name from the command line tools.
However, when I attempt to update the database, it fails.
Here is the commands I used

```
dotnet ef migrations add update1  -c MyDbContext

dotnet ef database update update1  -c MyDbContext
```

and it failed with

> There is already an object named MyTable in the database

which is a table which was created in the initial migration.

How can I tell it to either ignore the error, or else to only attempt to run the update1 migration?

**Edit:** deleting the table that was already there caused this odd behavior to stop happening and now it works as expected.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to remove the unwanted migration from the `__MigrationHistory` table.After that you can run your latest migration.This is happened due to you have manually deleted the table.B'cos EF doesn't know anything about your manual operations hence `__MigrationHistory` table still exist your old migration details (i.e. manually deleted table's record).

Answer (score 0):

In my case I used Ubuntu, EF 6 and the database was in the docker and it's doesn't updated DB.
I added --connection attribute and it's works, an example:

```
sudo dotnet ef database update --connection 
"Server=localhost;Database=temp;User Id=sa;Password=xxxxxxx;"
```